# Construct Uri object from fragment only

Tags: c#, .net, svg

Is it possible to create a `System.Uri` object from fragment only, e.g.

```
new System.Uri("#something", UriKind.Relative)
```

I tried that using both relative or absolute schemes, but it throws exception immediately.

### Background

Using Svg.NET, I'm creating an `SvgTextPath` object and need to assign its `ReferencedPath` property the ID of the parent path object, as suggested in [Mozilla SVG docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath). However, `ReferencePath` is of type `System.Uri` and does not accept simple string. How can I convert my element's ID to a Uri object?

Comment: I am putting this as a comment because I may be wrong but I previously worked with a project that uses mostly Relative URL and I hate `System.Uri` so much. It's absolutely useless when it comes to relative URLs. Almost every operation throws when your `Uri` is relative. You probably better go with some external library but the thing is there seem to be no one making them because well, `System.Uri` exists. I see [this one](https://github.com/balazsbotond/FluentUriBuilder), hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks @LukeVo, but that doesn't work. Even when I do not specify any other part of the URI and call `ToUri()` function of `FluentUriBuilder`, it generates `http://localhost#something`, which is not what I want. However I have found an alternate way of achieving my SVG task. See my answer below.

Comment: That makes sense. I remembered trying to solve the issue by putting a dummy host to make Uri absolute as well but then it comes with many issues. Like I said, it's absolutely bad when it comes to Relative. Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `System.Uri` nor `FluentUriBuilder` were able to generate a `System.Uri` object that would contain the fragment part only. I then found that `SvgTextPath` supports `CustomAttributes` and was able to add reference to my path object using the following simple line:

```
svgTextPath.CustomAttributes.Add("href", "#" + path.ID.ToString());
```

This works correctly and achieves text on path.

Hope Svg.NET guys change the type of `ReferencePath` property from `Uri` to `string` in the future.